# How to open a directory which contains subdirectory in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

can I open android directory mounted on sdcard should contain sub directories.
for example in ashish directory i had talasu and ash subdirectories.
The code which I had return :-

```
 String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

 File file = new File(root + "/ashish");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can access those directories, heres a little code to help you out

```
     File[] c = f.listFiles();//where f is your root directory(ashish)
   if (c != null) {
       for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
           if (c[i].isDirectory()) {
               //do whatever you want to do with subdirectories
           }
```